# unable to download kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, fedora

I am working on fedora 20 and having kernel **3.11.10-301.fc20.x86_64**

I want to download source code of this kernel version and to download it I am using command below

**yum install kernel-devel kernel-tools kernel-headers**

and I am getting error on terminal given below

[image]

I am unable to sought out this problem where I am getting wrong.

Comment: Update repositories and try again. Or download a new kernel from kernel.org

Comment: how to update repositories.... @user567879

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about writing software, but about downloading it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download the source of *any* package, just use:

```
yumdownloader --source <package-name>
```

To download the source for your current kernel:

```
yumdownloader --source kernel
```

You will have a source RPM package. You can then use `rpm2cpio` and `cpio` to get the sources including everything else in the package:

```
rpm2cpio <kernel-SRPM-name> | cpio -ivd
```

However, if you want the upstream kernel sources, you may be just better off downloading it from http://kernel.org.